# How do I pull from two tables depending on whether it contains Historical Data vs Forecasted Data based on the reporting year?

Tags: excel, dataframe, model, finance, forecasting

I have a data table from 2017-2030. The description is of each data point is layed out in rows while the years are layed out in columns. I want to pull information from the data table depending on whether the year I input in cell is the last year before the forecast begins into **one output table**.

Would anyone know how to approach this? Thank you!

Reporting Year Cell: 2022

**Historical**

2020 2021 2022

A

B

C

**Forecast**

2023 2024 2025

A

B

C

**Output Table**

2020 2021 2022 2023 2024 2025

A

B

C

I tried approaching with if statements but get confused on how to incorporate the years when they are in column format rather than row. I think an approach of if and match index is the right approach but am not entirely sure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.